expo v51 Error: Module "23" is missing from the asset registry
i am using react-native with expo it was working normally but recently expo needed an update from v50 to v51 so i installed it but now all i get is the massage Error: Module "23" is missing from the asset registry dose anybody no how to fix it?
i tried installing the latest versions of different dependencies but the error persistd

I also had same issue. There is command to fix upgrade dependencies npx expo install --fix. You can check more here.

will after uninstalling and installing random things something fixed it not sure what

This helped thanks a lot :D just deleted the .expo folder and node_modules then reinstalled the node modules with bun install and ran expo and now it's working
